# Kernel panic at boot and many programs segfault / core dump

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, chroot, segmentation-fault

Today I booted up an Ubuntu computer I last used when it was working fine 2 weeks ago, and now every kernel I have (4.15.x and 4.13.x) panics at the beginning of boot, including in recovery mode.

I can't read most of the kernel panic trace but the message is `not syncing: Attempted to kill init!`.

I checked the RAM with Memtest86+, and `fsck` the boot disk: both are fine, it is not solely a hardware issue as I can use the hardware with a Live USB.

I figured I would fix it by updating in a chroot from a Live USB. That doesn't work

```
root@ubuntu-mate:/# apt update
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
root@ubuntu-mate:/# python3
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
root@ubuntu-mate:/# ptrace
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
root@ubuntu-mate:/# gcc
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
root@ubuntu-mate:/# debsums
Illegal instruction (core dumped)    
root@ubuntu-mate:/# dpkg
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

(`ping`, `node` and `bash` work fine for some reason, but shared libraries shouldn't cause this)

Those programs are installed for `amd64` and they're running in a `chroot` on the very same `amd64` hardware, on a **very slightly** older (4.15.29 < 4.15.33) kernel than they were intended for. The Live USB and the original Ubuntu installation are both Ubuntu MATE 18.04.1 LTS, and they both have `libc6` version `2.27-3ubuntu1`, which should be the same ELF interpreter `ld-2.27.so`.

If I copy the Live USB's Python 3 to the chroot it doesn't work:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

And if I copy the original system's Python 3 to the Live system, it also doesn't work

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

If this were simply the original systems binaries being out of date relative to the CPU firmware, then one of these binaries should run in the other environment.

The two `python3`s have different checksums but the two `ld.so`s have the same checksums.

If I run `init` in the chroot (I don't know what that would actually do) the message is

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 540: 
elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion `ELFW(R_TYPE) (reloc->r_info) ==
R_X86_64_RELATIVE' failed!
```

It's hard to tell from [the code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h.html#526) since I'm not familiar with glibc symbols, but I guess `reloc->r_info` is not `8` (R_X86_64_RELATIVE) for my system's ELF binaries.

What's going on, and how can I recover the ability of my old system to interpret binaries?

the PPA list (not that any of these should be causing inconsistency in ld.so)

```
 
** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list:
deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list.save:
deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dr-graef-ubuntu-pure-lang_bionic-bionic.list:
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dr-graef/pure-lang.bionic/ubuntu bionic main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main 

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main 

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-bionic.list:
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-bionic.list.save:
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu artful main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list:
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x bionic main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list.save:
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x bionic main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list.save:
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snaipewastaken-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list:
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/snaipewastaken/ppa/ubuntu zesty main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snaipewastaken-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list.save:
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/snaipewastaken/ppa/ubuntu zesty main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:
deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main

** /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list.save:
deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main
```

Comment: My inclination would be to boot with Live USB and run `fsck` (file system check) on the hard disk / SSD. You may be able to boot in recovery mode and run `fsck` too but I've never run `fsck` so can't say for sure.

Comment: `cpuid` detects up to SSE4.2 and AVX in the Live USB as the original system's firmware also did, so I don't think it's about programs having compiled support for AVX/SSE

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix already fsck'd the drive, read the question :) can't boot into recovery mode, the kernel panics at the initial part of boot, i mentioned it too

Comment: Sorry I missed the `fsck`, couldn't see the forest through the trees...

Comment: Very strange situation. Are you sure that python3 is not overridden? Which PPAs do you have on problematic system? Did you run `debsums` on the system (from chroot or directly) to check its consistency?

Comment: @N0rbert python3 is as it comes from the official repository, see edits to many parts of the question, we don't have `debsums` because it crashes with `Illegal instruction`